# Simple JavaScript OnClick Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, onclick

I'm finally getting round to creating a website for my print design portfolio. I know exactly what I'm trying to achieve but being fairly new to web design I have found some limitations with the knowledge I have....

I have used css3 transitions (currently they only work in Chrome and Safari) to make flip cards which are triggered on hover - these work perfectly and are exactly what I am looking for. All I am now trying to do is add an JavaScript function (using jQuery) that permanently flips the card on click. I don't want it to disable the on hover function which is pure css though.

I have found this extremely difficult to implement.

The site is here:

[www.samueljamesdesign.com](http://www.samueljamesdesign.com)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Java and JavaScript are entirely different things. As far as I can tell, you meant JavaScript here. I've updated it for you.

Comment: For people to help you, you need to show the relevant code. Linking to your site isn't a substitute for that, because A) People shouldn't have to click through the link to help you, and B) Stack Overflow is meant to be a resource for you now, and for others later; the content of external links can change, move, or disappear entirely, rendering your question useless for people in the future.

Comment: @SamCorbet: The site is really nice, but T.J. Crowder is right - you should state what help exactly do you need, what have you tried and what was the result. Now it is hard to say what is being asked here, unfortunately. Edit your question.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid: You have duplicate IDs

Comment: FYI, the back of the cards is the same as the front on my machine.

Comment: Hi All, 

@T.J.Crowder apologies this is my first time using this forum and I am new to web design so apologies for my lack of knowledge - i make up for it with enthusiasm and willing to learn!

Tadeck Thank you I'm glad you like it :) I have done print based freelance work for years and thought it was about time I had a site to showcase some of my work. Designing stuff for yourself is so hard - I want it to portray exactly the right image and represent who I am as a designer.

Eric I did not know this was invalid - I will update the script where necessary - makes sense I should have know.

Comment: Eric what browser are you using? I'm aware that the css transition only works in chrome and safari.... I will be working on javascript workaround when I have mastered it better.

Comment: I'm using chrom on XP. It appears to be because I have an old graphics card, and `-webkit-backface-visibility` is ignored.To fix this, you can add and animate a z-index on the front and back of the flipcards - at present, the back face is always hidden by the front  face, for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just modify your CSS so that the rotation is also triggered by adding a class. For example, change this rule:

```
#card-container:hover .front {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}
```

To this:

```
.card-container:hover .front,
.card-container.selected .front,{
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}
```

Note that you *cannot* use `#card-container`, as it is invalid to have multiple elements with the same ID in the document. Set `card-container` as the class instead.

---

To make things stay flipeed when clicked, with your new CSS, you do:

```
var tiles = $('#tiles .card-container');
tiles.click(function() {
    tiles.removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');

    //To change the image in maincontent to match the
    //one in the flipcard clicked on:
    $('#maincontent .img-wrapper').empty().append($(this).find('img').clone());
});
```

Comment: Thank you! works a treat.... had to make one slight change.... the hover function wouldn't work when i had them separated with a ,

[code].card-container:hover .front
{
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}

.card-container.selected .front{
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}[code]

I had to separate them like that

Many thanks

Comment: Can I ask another question quickly please?

Im going to place images on each of the backs of the cards. How do I get different content to generate in the main_content div depending on which image is clicked on?

Many thanks

Sam

Comment: @SamCorbet: See my edit. I don't believe that it doesn't work with a single rule. It should work with the `,`. Next time, post code by putting it between `\``s

Comment: Thank you so much! where did you learn this all? I only have one small problem.... Firstly as default I don't want there to be an image in the main content. Secondly if one of the back of the cards doesn't have an image and you select it when you click back on one that does have an image it no longer loads....

I have left it as it is so you can see what I mean on the home page

Many thanks

Sam

Comment: @SamCorbet: Add `<div class="img-wrapper">` around your main image. I've edited my code accordingly.

Comment: Perfect thank you for all your help this is exactly what I was looking to achieve. How do I get the text to change depending on the image as well? I don't want the text to appear on the flip card only in the main content div when selected

Many thanks

Sam

Comment: Add an invisible div to each flipcard containing the content. Then do exactly the same thing that it currently does with the images: clone them, and add them to `#maincontent`

Comment: I added this 'code'<div class="text-wrapper"></div>'code' and '$('#main_content .text-wrapper').empty().append($(this).find('.info').clone());'

Im using this for my flip cards '<div class="info" style="display: none;">This is a test for image one</div>'

No joy... where am i going wrong? Why aren't my code tags working in here? Sam

Comment: @Sam: They are working, but they are still invisible. You need to make them invisible in the stylesheet, not through inline styles. `.card-container .info { display: none; }`