# Simple JavaScript function to persistently change the state of a button onclick?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, persistent

Does anyone have any simple JavaScript functions that persistently change the state of a button `onclick`? As in:

[button1] [button2] [button3]

Then, when you click button 1, something like this happens:

(((button1))) [button2] [button3]

Then, if you were to click button2, this would happen:

[button1] (((button2))) [button3]

Where the image associated with button 1 is changed, persistently.

I checked out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/4967732/73844 and this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/7991898/738448 but am having trouble seeing how they fit together to do what I want to do. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the code I've tried:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#prog
{
    margin: 5px 85px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
    background:url(prog_off.png) no-repeat;
    border: 0;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeImage() {
    test=document.getElementById("prog");
    test.backgroundImage="url(prog_on.png)";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" id="prog" onClick="changeImage()" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what do you mean by persistent? If you clicked button2 after clicking button1, would both buttons be depressed? or would button1 become unselected and button2 be depressed? Also, sample code would be helpful

Comment: button 1 would become depressed and button 2 would become pressed. I'll post up my code momentarily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/radio.html

If so, it'll be easier (and better since its tested across all browsers etc..) using jQuery UI's button widget instead of developing afresh.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#radio